# Grails remoteFunction ajax assistance

Tags: ajax, grails

I'm really struggling with getting the percentage value of progress that is continuously being updated in a function on my controller to appear in template GSP page using `remoteFunction`.

This is my controller code and "progressData" is sent from a service to constantly update the current progress of a task:

```
def progress(progressData) {

   def statusToView = progressData

   [statusToView: statusToView]
}
```

and in my _progress.gsp page:

```
<g:javascript>
    setInterval( "refreshMe();", 300 );
    function refreshMe(){
       ${remoteFunction(action:'progress', controller:'data')}
    }
</g:javascript>
```

The controller is expecting the property `progressData` which is doesn't get from the `remoteFunction`, and so I'm guessing I have to think to do this another way but I'm just at a bit of a loss now. Plus I'm not getting the value `statusToView` within the GSP because of this.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, your action `progress` is actually waiting for the `progressData` param, which is not passed.
If your `progressData` value is stored somewhere in your gsp page, you should change your remoteFunction in this way or similar:

```
$remoteFunction(action: 'progress', controller: 'data', update: [success: 'great', failure: 'ohno'], params: '\'progressData=\' + progressData')
```

Regarding `update: [success: ... ]`, [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html) you can find the description of the various attributes.

Comment: thanks, tried to implement the above but I always seem to get the failure as my statusToView never seems to update within the view

Comment: remoteFunction is also being depreciated in Grails 3+